# How to use dplyr SE with "invalid" names (ie containing spaces)?

Tags: r, dplyr

I can't figure out how to use SE dplyr function with invalid variable names, for example selecting a variable with a space in it.

Example:

```
df <- dplyr::data_frame(`a b` = 1)
myvar <- "a b"
```

If I want to select `a b` variable, I can do it with `` dplyr::select(df, `a b`) ``, but how do I do that with `select_`?

I suppose I just need to find a function that "wraps" a string in backticks, so that I can call `dplyr::select_(df, backtick(myvar))`

Comment: My first suggestion would be don't use invalid names! Why would you do that?

Comment: developing an app that allows user to change the name of a variable, and for biologists many times they'd prefer to have spaces in a name, it'd hard to put a note "do not use spaces or special characters", it'll look weird for them.

Comment: @divide_by_zero yes I can do that if I know the variable name, but if I don't then I need to someone "wrap" the variable in backticks. How can I achieve what you did with using `myvar` instead of hardcoding `a b`?

Comment: `backtick<-function(x) paste0("\`", x, "\`")`

Comment: You can also take whatever the user gives you and run it through `make.names()` to make it a valid name. it's not great idea to mix variable names with "friendly" names that you show to the user. You probably want to keep those separate.

Comment: @MrFlick thanks that certainly works. Is this so rarely done/discouraged that it's purposely not part of base R? It just feels hacky to have to do this, I was hoping R had a way to do it natively.

Comment: @MrFlick the slight problem with using make.names is that there's no way to go backwards, so the user will see a name with periods in it and will get confused. It'd be nice if there was an inverse function for `make.names`. Thanks for your input

Comment: There are `sQuote` and `dQuote` for single and double quotes, but nothing for back ticks because, yes, this should generally be avoided. You should use proper symbol names as column names. Otherwise other things are likely to break as well.

Comment: Ok, I'll just have to think a bit more on tradeoff of making user happy vs being R-safe, thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As MyFlick said in the comments, this behaviour should generally be avoided, but if you want to make it work you can make your own backtick wrapper

```
backtick <- function(x) paste0("`", x, "`")
dplyr::select_(df, backtick(myvar))
```

EDIT: Hadley replied to my tweets about this and showed me that simply using `as.name` will work for this instead of using backticks:

```
df <- dplyr::data_frame(`a b` = 1)
myvar <- "a b"
dplyr::select_(df, as.name(myvar))
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to exploit the ability of `select` to use column *positions*. The `as.name` solution did not appear to work for some of my columns.

```
select(df, which(names(df) %in% myvar))
```

or even more succinctly if already in a pipe:

```
df %>%
 select(which(names(.) %in% myvar))
```

Although this uses `select`, in my view it does not rely on NSE.

Note that if there are no matches, all columns will be dropped with no error or warning.