# how to pass column names in dplyr select without evaluation

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to programmatically pass column names to a function so that they can be selected in dplyr. The column names will vary so I've tried to use the standard evaluation version of the select function `select_`. The column names themselves are a bit funny as they contain `+` and `-` characters, which I think is causing the issue. Below is a simple example that replicates the error.

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
data <- data_frame(target_id = 'xyz',
                   `CH4+Sulfate-1` = 1.2, 
                   `CH4+Sulfate-2` = 2, 
                   `CH4+Sulfate-3` = 3)
columns <- c('CH4+Sulfate-1', 'CH4+Sulfate-2', 'CH4+Sulfate-3')
select_(data, .dots = columns)
```

I get the following error

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'CH4' not found
```

Which leads me to believe that the names are being evaluated rather than taken as the string. How can I get around this problem without having to rename the columns of the table?

Comment: Hmmm.... good question - `data[columns]` from base R works okay so it's not a universal issue. You can also hack around it with `dplyr::select(data, match(columns, names(data)) )` but I have no idea otherwise.

Comment: An absolutely minimal example is enough to break it - `dat <- data.frame(\`A+B\`=1:3,check.names=FALSE); select_(dat, "A+B")`

Comment: It seems like `one_of` with `select` can be the answer in these [sorts of situations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35839408/r-dplyr-drop-multiple-columns/35839679#35839679): `select(data, one_of(columns))`

Comment: [Questions/answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30789086/how-to-use-dplyr-se-with-invalid-names-ie-containing-spaces) closely related.  The accpeted answer shows the use of `as.name` as an option to avoid the back-ticks.  However, to get this to work on a vector you would need to loop through the vector or make a vectorized version of `as.name` (`v.as.name = Vectorize(as.name)`)

Comment: thanks aosmith, your solution with vectorizing `as.name` worked. I'd be happy to accept it/up vote it if you put it in as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping the names in backticks does the job.

```
columns <- c('`CH4+Sulfate-1`', '`CH4+Sulfate-2`', '`CH4+Sulfate-3`')
```